# React component to list TV shows from a JSON result

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, react.js, jsx

I'm trying to rewrite my old project in Reactjs. As I am a beginner and this is my first app, I need some assistance in understanding what is the best way to do this in the React way and how I can improve myself and this demo project.

Here is a [working demo](http://numberless-home.surge.sh/) of it.

**ListManager.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import List from './List'

export class ListManager extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
       super(props, context)
       this.state = { finaldata :[]}
}


APIres(ids){
    Promise.all(ids.map(id =>
        fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/'+id).then(resp => resp.json().then(data => data.name))
        )).then(data => {
            data.sort()
            this.setState({finaldata:data})
        })
}

componentWillMount(){
    const id = [1,2,3,4,5]
    this.APIres(id)

}

render() {

    return ( 
        < div >
            <h3>{this.props.title}< /h3> 

            <List data={this.state.finaldata} />
        < /div >
    )
  }
}
```

**List.js**

```
'use strict'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const ListItem = (props) => <li>{ props.text }</li>

const List = (props) => {
    const listNodes = props.data.map((
    value,index) => {
        return(
            <ListItem text={value} key={index}></ListItem>
        )
    })

    return ( <ul>{listNodes}</ul>
    )
}

export default List
```

Some note: `id` array will come with a URL query like `example.com/#/?id=1,2,3,4`. I will be using react-router for this.

Comment: @200_success  thanks for edit . last line was important . i want to show name released to id as soon its request its done .  i know for that Promise is wrong thing to use for it .

Comment: Code Review is a site for open-ended critique of code that already works as intended. If you happen to get an answer that suggests a way to load results in parallel, then great. But asking how to implement it would be off-topic.

Comment: Please don't take this as an insult -- i don't know how to phrase this in a softer way -- if this code is formatted the same way as your files are, you may want to read a few javascript style guidelines, make some decisions based on what you like, and install some tool such as eslint to help you keep your style consistent.

Personally, I like the airbnb style guide: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Comment: I use this one: https://github.com/feross/standard. It's excellent and its look nice. I don't know why my code looks like this. I tried to fix in StackOverflow, but I was failed.

Look at this code: http://prntscr.com/dmrw7l

Comment: need help in this now ??

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473302/show-result-from-parallel-ajax-request-in-react-component/39486654#39486654

Answer (score 1):

A few things to change. Move the api request to `componentDidMount` because `componentWillMount` is considered legacy now. Rename the method thats making the api request to be more *declarative* which is to be more descriptive of whats its doing. Move the list of ids into the method thats making the api request. All of those changes + the changes to the api request from your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473302/show-result-from-parallel-ajax-request-in-react-component/39486654#39486654 would look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import List from "./List";

class ListManager extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      listData: []
    };

    this.getListData = this.getListData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getListData();
  }

  getListData() {
    const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    let listData = [];

    ids.forEach(id =>
      fetch("http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/" + id)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(show => {
          listData.push(show);
        })
    );

    this.setState({
      listData: listData.sort((a, b) => a.runtime - b.runtime)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
        <List data={this.state.listData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListManager;
```